# How to filter only one polygon in a map in R

Tags: r, shapefile, rgdal

I am generating a map below using a `shapefile` file. The map refers to a state of a specific country. Now I would like to show the map only one municipality. In this case, I would like the municipality called `Ponta Grossa`. I believe you have to do something like:  `NM_MUNICIP == PONTA GROSSA`. `NM_MUNICIP` is an attribute of the shapefile.

```
> names(shp)

[1] "NM_MUNICIP" "CD_GEOCMU"
```

Executable code below:

```
library(rgdal)

temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()
download.file("https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip",temp)

unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
shp <- readOGR(temp2)

plot(shp)
```

[image]

Comment: You've asked 3 Q's on this same shapefile, you could have condensed them all into one Q.  Anyway, I find it easier to convert it to sf  `sf::st_as_sf(shp) |> 
  filter(NM_MUNICIP  == "PONTA GROSSA") |> 
  plot()`, I'll be honest if you have more Q's on plotting spatial data I would recommend you check out https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset by the attribute to return only `PONTA GROSSA`:

```
shp_subset <- shp[shp$NM_MUNICIP == "PONTA GROSSA",]

plot(shp_subset)
```

Or you can also use `subset`:

```
subset(shp, NM_MUNICIP == "PONTA GROSSA") |>
  plot()
```

[image]